# Program for debug and test .cg files

Tags: opengl, cg

I have several Cg files which was hand-made. As I am a beginner in Cg, I would like to use some pre-existing tool which can load a .cg file as material for a shape. Which tool would be appropriate for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think nVidia's [FX Composer](http://developer.nvidia.com/fx-composer) should work.

Comment: FX Composer only load CgFX file. The Cg files I have are separate vertex/fragment files.

Comment: Right -- I believe you'll have to create a CgFX file, then cut-n-paste in your separate shaders. Granted, that's not exactly convenient, but it's the closest I know of with existing tools.

Comment: My shader also use textures, how I can accomplish this with FX Composer.

Comment: @Dat Chu: It will let you load a texture from most of the typical bitmap file formats (BMP, JPEG, etc.) as well as some slightly less common ones like OpenEXR and frames from h.264 video.

Comment: Any chance of a cross-platform app?

Comment: In theory there's no reason it couldn't be done, but if one is currently available, I'm not aware of it.